# Matlab 2D tsunami simulation

Tags: matlab, simulation, numerical-methods, differential-equations, pde

I need to solve the 2D wave equation, which is written as follows:

[image]

Using Matlab, I have to simulate a 2D tsunami generated by an earthquake, given Neumann condition, a given function for lambda and a gaussian as initial displacement.
The lambda function provided by the exercise is the one I've used in the code.

The code I've written is (I'm just learning how to program):

```
% Define simulation parameters
Lx = 1000; % domain size in x-direction
Ly = 1000; % domain size in y-direction
Nx = 100; % number of grid points in x-direction
Ny = 100; % number of grid points in y-direction
dx = Lx/Nx; % grid spacing in x-direction
dy = Ly/Ny; % grid spacing in y-direction
g = 9.81;
H0 = 10; % mean water depth
c = sqrt(g*H0); % wave speed
theta = 1; % inclination angle
T = 150; % total simulation time
dt = 0.1; % time step

% Define the variable diffusion coefficient
lambda = zeros(Ny, Nx); % variable diffusion coefficient
X_0 = Lx/2; % point where the sea bed changes
G = g*H0; % maximum value of lambda
for i = 1:Nx
    for j = 1:Ny
        if (i-1)*dx < X_0
            lambda(j,i) = G;
        else
            lambda(j,i) = g*(H0 - ((i-1)*dx-X_0)*0.0174550649282176);
        end
    end
end

% Initialize the solution
u = zeros(Ny, Nx); % current solution
u_old = zeros(Ny, Nx); % previous solution
u_xx = zeros(Ny, Nx); % second derivative in x-direction
u_yy = zeros(Ny, Nx); % second derivative in y-direction
D_xx = zeros(Ny, Nx); % diffusion term in x-direction
D_yy = zeros(Ny, Nx); % diffusion term in y-direction

% Define the initial conditions
sigmax = 10; % width of the Gaussian function
sigmay = 30;
x0 = Lx/2; % x-coordinate of the center of the Gaussian function
y0 = Ly/2; % y-coordinate of the center of the Gaussian function
u0 = 2*exp(-(dx*(0:Nx-1)-x0).^2/(sigmax^2))'*exp(-(dy*(0:Ny-1)-y0).^2/(sigmay^2)); % Gaussian function
u = u0; % set the initial condition

% Visualization
[X, Y] = meshgrid(dx*(0:Nx-1), dy*(0:Ny-1)); % create grid for plotting
surf(X, Y, u); % plot the initial condition
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
zlabel('Surface Elevation');
title(sprintf('Time = %.3f', 0));
axis([0 Lx 0 Ly -max(max(u0)) max(max(u0))]);
view(3);
colorbar;
drawnow;

% Initialize maximum wave elevation at coastline
max_elevation = max(u(end, :));

% Time-stepping loop
for n = 1:(T/dt)
    % Calculate the second derivatives using finite differences
    u_xx = (circshift(u, [0 -1]) - 2*u + circshift(u, [0 1]))/(dx^2);
    u_yy = (circshift(u, [-1 0]) - 2*u + circshift(u, [1 0]))/(dy^2);

    % Calculate the diffusion terms using the variable diffusion coefficient
    D_xx = lambda.*u_xx;
    D_yy = lambda.*u_yy;
        % Calculate the CFL condition
    max_lambda = max(max(lambda));
    CFL = dt <= 1/(c*sqrt((1/dx^2) + (1/dy^2)));
    if CFL > 1
        dt = 0.9/(c*sqrt((1/dx^2) + (1/dy^2)));
    end
    
    % Calculate the boundary terms using the Neumann boundary condition
    u(:, 1) = u(:, 2);
    u(:, end) = u(:, end-1);
    u(1, :) = u(2, :);
    u(end, :) = u(end-1, :);
    
    % Update the solution using the wave equation with variable diffusion coefficient
    u_new = 2*u - u_old + c^2*dt^2*(u_xx + u_yy) + dt^2*D_xx + dt^2*D_yy;
    
    % Update the solution for the next time step
    u_old = u; % store the current solution
    u = u_new; % update the solution
    
    % Update maximum wave elevation at coastline
    max_elevation = max(max_elevation, max(u(end, :)));
    
    % Visualization
    surf(X, Y, u); % plot the surface elevation
    xlabel('x');
    ylabel('y');
    zlabel('Surface Elevation');
    title(sprintf('Time = %.3f', n*dt));
    axis([0 Lx 0 Ly -50 50]);
    view(3);
    colorbar;
    drawnow;
end

% Print the maximum wave elevation at the coastline
fprintf('Maximum wave elevation at coastline: %.3f\n', max_elevation);
```

And it runs correctly. The exercise asks me to consider: sigmax=80000 m, sigmay=200000 m and H0= 5000m . So i've modified the code in this way:

```
% Define simulation parameters
Lx = 1000e3; % domain size in x-direction (set to 1000 km)
Ly = 1000e3; % domain size in y-direction (set to 1000 km)
Nx = 100; % number of grid points in x-direction
Ny = 100; % number of grid points in y-direction
dx = Lx/Nx; % grid spacing in x-direction
dy = Ly/Ny; % grid spacing in y-direction
g = 9.81;
H0 = 5000; % mean water depth (set to 5000 meters)
c = sqrt(g*H0); % wave speed
theta = 1; % inclination angle
T = 600; % total simulation time
dt = 0.1; % time step

% Define the variable diffusion coefficient
lambda = zeros(Ny, Nx); % variable diffusion coefficient
X_0 = Lx/2; % point where the sea bed changes
G = g*H0; % maximum value of lambda
for i = 1:Nx
    for j = 1:Ny
        if (i-1)*dx < X_0
            lambda(j,i) = G;
        else
            lambda(j,i) = g*(H0 - ((i-1)*dx-X_0)*0.0174550649282176);
        end
    end
end

% Initialize the solution
u = zeros(Ny, Nx); % current solution
u_old = zeros(Ny, Nx); % previous solution
u_xx = zeros(Ny, Nx); % second derivative in x-direction
u_yy = zeros(Ny, Nx); % second derivative in y-direction
D_xx = zeros(Ny, Nx); % diffusion term in x-direction
D_yy = zeros(Ny, Nx); % diffusion term in y-direction

% Define the initial conditions
sigmay = 200e3; % width of the Gaussian function (set to 200 km)
sigmax = 80e3;
x0 = Lx/2; % x-coordinate of the center of the Gaussian function
y0 = Ly/2; % y-coordinate of the center of the Gaussian function
u0 = 2*exp(-(dx*(0:Nx-1)-x0).^2/(sigmax^2))'*exp(-(dy*(0:Ny-1)-y0).^2/(sigmay^2)); % Gaussian function
u = u0; % set the initial condition

% Visualization
[X, Y] = meshgrid(dx*(0:Nx-1), dy*(0:Ny-1)); % create grid for plotting
surf(X, Y, u); % plot the initial condition
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
zlabel('Surface Elevation');
title(sprintf('Time = %.3f', 0));
axis([0 Lx 0 Ly -max(max(u0)) max(max(u0))]);
view(3);
colorbar;
drawnow;

% Initialize maximum wave elevation at coastline
max_elevation = max(u(end, :));
% Time-stepping loop
for n = 1:(T/dt)
    % Calculate the second derivatives using finite differences
    u_xx = (circshift(u, [0 -1]) - 2*u + circshift(u, [0 1]))/(dx^2);
    u_yy = (circshift(u, [-1 0]) - 2*u + circshift(u, [1 0]))/(dy^2);
    % Calculate the diffusion terms using the variable diffusion coefficient
    D_xx = lambda.*u_xx;
    D_yy = lambda.*u_yy;
    max_lambda = max(max(lambda));
    CFL = dt <= 1/(c*sqrt((1/dx^2) + (1/dy^2)));
    if CFL > 1
        dt = 0.9/(c*sqrt((1/dx^2) + (1/dy^2)));
    end
    % Calculate the boundary terms using the Neumann boundary condition
    u(:, 1) = u(:, 2);
    u(:, end) = u(:, end-1);
    u(1, :) = u(2, :);
    u(end, :) = u(end-1, :);
    % Update the solution using the wave equation with variable diffusion coefficient
    u_new = 2*u - u_old + c^2*dt^2*(u_xx + u_yy) + dt^2*D_xx + dt^2*D_yy;
    % Update the solution for the next time step
    u_old = u; % store the current solution
    u = u_new; % update the solution
    % Update maximum wave elevation at coastline
    max_elevation = max(max_elevation, max(u(end, :)));
    % Visualization
    surf(X, Y, u); % plot the surface elevation
    xlabel('x');
    ylabel('y');
    zlabel('Surface Elevation');
    title(sprintf('Time = %.3f', n*dt));
    axis([0 Lx 0 Ly -max(max(u0)) max(max(u0))]);
    view(3);
    colorbar;
    drawnow;
    pause(0.01)
end

% Print the maximum wave elevation at the coastline
fprintf('Maximum wave elevation at coastline: %.3f\n', max_elevation);
```

The problem is that when i run the simulation, it seems that the time runs but the plot not. I visualize only the initial gaussian and not its propagation. Can anybody help me?

Thank you in advance for your interest and attention.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Please [edit] your question to replace the screenshots with [formatted text](/help/formatting)

Comment: As you've noted, Stack Overflow does not support TeX-rendering. Either try to write your equations as well as it goes using "normal" ASCII, or provide a screenshot of the equation. (cc @PranavHosangadi about the code, data and text you're absolutely right, TeX equations are an exception.)

Comment: @Adriaan my bad, I inlined the screenshot of the equation and left the other two screenshots as links in my original edit, but I didn't make it clear that the equation was OK as an image

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, it's my first question here, so I'm trying to learn the rules as well.